# Logout on browser close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

Is there any way to logout on browser close while using jwt token in local storage for authentication in MeanStack application.

I have used  beforeunload but it is called on refresh and few other events as well.

Comment: The users' session should end when they close the browser. Use that information to see if they should still be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. The only difference is that `sessionStorage` is only meant to survive the current browser session.  Another option would be to store your application state in memory (in a variable) and it will be gone on close.

Comment: storing jwt token in Session Storage will make application to work in different tabs with same login ? Applications should work in multiple tabs once logged in